# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to build an app with fragments, which are at the beginner level and I have no direct solid knowledge or experience in the subject.

I want WebViewFragment be visible when the app starts, before later adding a ListView side.

As it stands now, the app crashes as soon as I start it on the phone. I have paste the errorlog below.

**ERROR**

```
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050): Process: com.raj.fragment, PID: 25050
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.raj.fragment/com.raj.fragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1264)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1080)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at com.raj.fragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    ... 11 more
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.raj.fragment.WebViewFragment that is not a Fragment
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    ... 21 more
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
01-01 18:14:24.223: E/AndroidRuntime(25050):    ... 25 more
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

**WebViewFragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);

        mWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/about/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());

        return view;    
    }

    public class WebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
        {
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


       <fragment 
            android:name="com.raj.fragment.WebViewFragment"
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Trying to instantiate a class com.raj.fragment.WebViewFragment that is not a Fragment
```

The log says it all

Change to

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
```

Because you have

```
<fragment android:name="com.raj.fragment.WebViewFragment" // is a fragment
```

Your `Fragment` is hosted by the `MainActivity`.

Also you can have either `class="com.raj.fragment.WebViewFragment"` or `android:name="com.raj.fragment.WebViewFragment"`. No need to have both.

Also add @Override annotation

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
```

Edit:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);// missing  
}
```

Comment: Thank You!But when I add the @Override, Eclipse giving me "The method onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) of type WebViewFragment must override or implement a supertype method" :/

Comment: @user2734182 its just a annotation to indicate a that its a overriden method. It should work without it though

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.raj.fragment.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity"

Comment: @user2734182 post your updated code both activity code and the fragment code along with import statements

Comment: Now it works =) Or yes, the app starts but is blank / white: S

Comment: @user2734182 i don't understand your comment if you have a problem post the updated code and specify what problem you are facing

Comment: Whell, it works without errormessage now. I just "cleaned" the project =) But the app is blank/white

Comment: @user2734182 i can't guess or provide a suggestion without the updated code.

Comment: I did that you told me to do... I changed to public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment { and I use android:name="com.raj.fragment.WebViewFragment" instead of both name and class

Comment: @user2734182 if you can't post the update by editing to your post. sorry i can't help further

Comment: @user2734182 you miss `setContentView`. This should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The WebViewFragment should not be a FragmentActivity. Since it is a fragment it should inherit Fragment.

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment
```